# Change center of projection (QGIS)

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, pyqgis

I'm working with [this](https://astrogeology.usgs.gov/search/map/Pluto/NewHorizons/Pluto_NewHorizons_Global_DEM_300m_Jul2017)
mosaic from Pluto.
It is projected in simple cylindrical.

I need help to change, using PyQGIS, the center of the projection to the coordinates of a specific point, or to a coordinate related to a point plotted in the mosaic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing `lat_0` and `lon_0` values to change the center. Here I use a cylindrical "projection" (it's a sphere...)

```
# Create a custom projection using a globe with radius 1188300 meters and lon_0 (x) eqal -0.452751 and lat_0 (y) eqal 51.470129

pluto = QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem("PROJ:+proj=ortho +lat_0=51.470129 +lon_0=-0.452751 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +a=1188300 +b=1188300 +units=m +no_defs")

pluto.saveAsUserCrs('Mypluto') # Save the definition so can be reusable later
QgsProject.instance().setCrs(pluto)
```

In your case, you may want to reuse the projection you already using with

```py
map_proj = QgsProject.instance().crs()
proj_representation = map_proj.toProj()

params_replacement = {
    '+lon_0': 20,
    '+lat_0': 80
}
new_proj_definition = []
for i in proj_representation.split(' '):
    splitted = i.split('=')
    if len(splitted) == 2 and params_replacement.get(splitted[0]):
        new_proj_definition.append('='.join([
            str(splitted[0]),
            str(params_replacement[splitted[0]])
        ]))
    else:
        new_proj_definition.append(i)

new_proj_string = ' '.join(new_proj_definition)
pluto2 = QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem("PROJ:" + proj_representation)

pluto2.saveAsUserCrs('Mypluto2') # Save the definition so can be reusable later
QgsProject.instance().setCrs(pluto2)
```

Although the second part of the recipe changes the x and y center of the projection, I got some issue to understand why the change of the center seems to have no effects although proj values has been changed.

Projections specialists wanted :)